# Would it be possible you create a retropie cluster that would run the different processes on each individual pi?

Tags: networking, hardware, retropie, cluster

Hi I'm kind of new to the whole raspberry pi thing and have been researching about retropie that allows you to emulate games on the pi. Anyway would it be possible to create a raspberry pi cluster that could run more intensive emulations such as ps2 games?

Looking at raspberry pi clusters, they run a program in parallel breaking the process down between pi's with a master in charge of the whole thing. Could you apply this methodology to this situation where you have a head node in charge of the whole task and the other pi's running a seperate thread on all of them? For example: two nodes running the graphics thread, one node running the audio thread; recompiling the code and the master node telling the rest what to do. I understand network limitations as tranfering all the data could be a problem with the 100Mbs cap on the ethernet but if you were to forget about that would it be possible?

Comment: I realize this isn't an exact duplicate of those other questions, but it is close enough if the question is really, "Is this worth pursuing?".  As to whether the exact application you have in mind is *possible*, I'd say in theory it is but it would not be simple or easy and (to be blunt) if you had anywhere near the technical skills (this would require a *lot* of programming  work, with years of previous experience), you probably would not be asking the question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes if you forgot about the bandwidth and latency of usb2, but then once you remembered that limitation it would not be worth it.